# What does this line from "Independence" mean?

Tags: legacy-fleet

I'm confused by this line on page 2 of Nick Webb's book ["Independence"](https://www.amazon.com.br/Independence-Book-Legacy-Fleet-English-ebook/dp/B01LWT2PK6):

> The Galactic People’s Congress wasn’t big enough yet to preclude the old man himself from giving the thumbs-up on even standard delivery missions.

He could give the thumbs up even on standard delivery missions? I don't know what this means.

Why could he give the thumbs up “on even standard delivery missions”?

Comment: I wasn't sure what to tag this with, so I created a tag for the series "Independence" is part of, rather than a tag for the novel itself.

Comment: Who is "the old man himself"?  I assume that it's the Galactic President or some such, but more context would be helpful

Comment: The old man himself is the Secretary General it’s on the same page

Answer (score 2):

He would sometimes personally approve standard delivery missions.  Normally, one would expect a high-ranking official to be dealing with bigger issues, but given that the Congress is so small, they don't have the levels of bureaucracy to handle it -- and probably not the number of missions that would require such a bureaucracy.

Comment: So standard delivery missions are bigger issues?what are the other types of Delivery missons?

Comment: @Guilherme, no, standard delivery missions are minor missions. That’s why it’s surprising the highest ranking official would be involved in approving them.